# about moving items in selectbox

Tags: javascript

I am trying to moving the items in a select box by using buttons.. for this i used swapNode().
But it is working only in IE. in chrome not working how to make it to work in chrome
Here is my code

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Moving the options up and down in Multiple select box </title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function move(id)
 {

if (id=='up')
{
    var len=    document.f1.selectbox1.options.length;
    if (document.f1.selectbox1[0].selected)
    {
        alert("This is the first record");
        return false;
    }
    var up_id=document.f1.selectbox1.selectedIndex;
    document.f1.selectbox1[up_id].swapNode(document.f1.selectbox1[up_id-1]);
}
if (id=='down')
{
 var len=document.f1.selectbox1.options.length;
    if (document.f1.selectbox1[len-1].selected)
    {
        alert("This is last record");
        return false;
    }
    var down_id=document.f1.selectbox1.selectedIndex;
    document.f1.selectbox1[down_id].swapNode(document.f1.selectbox1[down_id+1]);
}
if (id=='top')
{
    var len=document.f1.selectbox1.options.length;
    if (document.f1.selectbox1[0].selected)
    {
        alert("This is the first record");
        return false;
    }
    var top_id=document.f1.selectbox1.selectedIndex
    for (var j=top_id;j>0 ;j-- )
    {   
            document.f1.selectbox1[j].swapNode(document.f1.selectbox1[j-1]);
    }
}
if (id=='bottom')
{
    var len=document.f1.selectbox1.options.length;;
    if(document.f1.selectbox1[len-1].selected)
        {
            alert("This is last record");
            return false;
        }
        var bot_id=document.f1.selectbox1.selectedIndex
        for (var k=bot_id; k<len-1;k++)
        {
                document.f1.selectbox1[k].swapNode(document.f1.selectbox1[k+1]);

        }
}
 }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form name="f1">
<select multiple size="20" style="width:30%" name="selectbox1" id="select_box">
<option id="1">First item</option>
<option id="2">Second item</option>
<option id="3">Third item</option>
<option id="4">Fourth item</option>
<option id="4">Fifth item</option>
<option id="4">Sixth item</option>
<option id="4">Seventh item</option>
<option id="4">Eighth item</option>
<option id="4">Ninth item</option>
<option id="4">Tenth item</option>
</select><br>
<input type="button" value="Up" onClick="move('up')">
<input type="button" value="Down" onClick="move('down')">
<input type="button" value="Top" onClick="move('top')">
<input type="button" value="Bottom" onClick="move('bottom')">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

swapNode() is a Microsoft DOM extension and so as a result will not be recognized by browsers other than IE.

I ran your example in FireFox and used FireBug (You should download this plugin and use it in situations like this if you don't already) and sure enough the console was throwing an error that swapNode() was "not a function".

If I were to advise you from here, I would suggest going to lookup a jQuery plugin or something of that sort that achieves this kind functionality. Libraries like jQuery tend to offer cross browser solutions to these sorts of javascript problems and best of all are more often then not open source (so you can have a peek at the code and rework your own implementation if you would like).
http://jquery.com/

Alternatively, you could simply provide the swapNode() function in your code so that other browsers could pick it up. If you plan to go this route, you should be able to find an implementation with a quick Google search. I have provided a link to one such implementation below (I have not reviewed or used this code, use only after reviewing). In my humble opinion however, it is best to avoid solutions that have browser dependency as they are not always future proof and can often result in unforeseen issues.
http://sundberg.it/2006/05/12/swapnode_in_firefox

Good Luck!

Comment: This might also be helpful to you: http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/lib/selectbox/jquery.php